# Probability of tossing a coin where pr(heads) = p

Tags: probability

Toss a coin (Prob of heads = $p$) $n$ times. Let $X =$ # of heads. Suppose $X=k$ ($1 \leq k \leq n$). What is the probability that the $i-th$ toss was heads?

P($i-th$ toss = heads) = $n^p$? but that doesn't seem correct.

This seems similar to a binomial distribution problem in my book

Comment: Coin tosses are generally assumed to be independent. Also, $n^p\ge 1$ is probably not the right answer if you're looking at probabilities. ;-)

Comment: To understand the importance of k, compare k==n to k==1 intuitively. What can it tell about the ith coin toss?

Comment: @Juanito so we know if $k=n$ then all the flips are heads and if $k=1$ then we only got one head. So we have at least 1 head and at most $n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are told how many heads came up, we don't care what the abstract probability of heads is.  We have a list of length $n$ with $k$ heads and $n-k$ tails.  Now you pick one of the items of the list at random.  What is the chance you get heads?

Comment: No, presumably $k \lt n$, so ${k \choose n}=0$.  Think about putting $k$ slips of paper labeled "heads" in a hat and $n-k$ slips labeled "tails".  Now draw one.  What is the chance it says "heads"?  Do you see why this is the same question?

Comment: Okay the list length $n$ makes sense and since we let $X = k$, $k$ is how many heads we get and $n - k$ makes up the rest which has to be tails. But I can't figure out which equation to use for randomly selecting a coin to get heads...

Comment: Okay so that is the same question basically because we just want to know what the chances are that any flip we choose is heads

Comment: That is correct.  So what fraction of the flips were heads?

Comment: would it be $\frac{k - (n - k)}{n}$?

Comment: No, that will be negative if (say) $k=1, n=10$.  You need probabilities always to be between $0$ and $1$.  It is simpler than that.  You have $k$ heads out of $n$ flips, so the chance of a head is $\frac kn$

Comment: oh I see. then is it just $\frac{k}{n}$

Comment: So then the $i-th$ toss being heads would be $\frac{k^i}{n}$? or do I not even need the $i$ in the equation?

Comment: No, you don't need the $i$.  The $i$ just picks a particular toss.  Again, if $i$ is large that will be greater than $1$ and can't be a probability.  The chance the first toss was heads is the same as the chance the last toss was heads.

Comment: Awesome! I really appreciate you walking me through this, I have a hard time with probability if you can't tell and it's nice to understand what I am doing!

Comment: does it matter that the probability of heads isn't $\frac{1}{2}$ in this case since P(heads)= $p$ ?

Comment: No, because we are told how many heads and tails there are and we are picking from that list.  If $k=3, n=5$, that could be a reasonably likely event from $p=0.6$ or a rare event from $p=0.1$ The chance that a randomly selected toss is heads is $\frac 35$ in either case.

Comment: perfect thanks!!